# How to split this string with python?

Tags: python, string, split

I have strings that look like this example:
"AAABBBCDEEEEBBBAA"

Any character is possible in the string.

I want to split it to a list like:
['AAA','BBB','C','D','EEEE','BBB','AA']

so every continuous stretch of the same characters goes to separate element of the split list.

I know that I can iterate over characters in the string, check every i and i-1 pair if they contain the same character, etc. but is there a more simple solution out there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [''.join(g) for k, g in groupby('AAAABBBCCD')]
['AAAA', 'BBB', 'CC', 'D']
```

And by normal string manipulation

```
>>> a=[];S="";p=""
>>> s
'AAABBBCDEEEEBBBAA'
>>> for c in s:
...     if c != p: a.append(S);S=""
...     S=S+c
...     p=c
...
>>> a.append(S)
>>> a
['', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'C', 'D', 'EEEE', 'BBB', 'AA']
>>> filter(None,a)
['AAA', 'BBB', 'C', 'D', 'EEEE', 'BBB', 'AA']
```

Answer (score 15):

We could use Regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile(r'(.)\1*')
>>> [m.group() for m in r.finditer('AAABBBCDEEEEBBBAA')]
['AAA', 'BBB', 'C', 'D', 'EEEE', 'BBB', 'AA']
```

---

Alternatively, we could use [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

```
>>> import itertools
>>> [''.join(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby('AAABBBCDEEEEBBBAA')]
['AAA', 'BBB', 'C', 'D', 'EEEE', 'BBB', 'AA']
```

`timeit` shows Regex is faster (for this particular string) ([Python 2.6](http://ideone.com/kYJUQ), [Python 3.1](http://ideone.com/cZWWm)). But Regex is after all specialized for string, and `groupby` is a generic function, so this is not so unexpected.

Comment: Wow, thanks, regex solution is cool, groupby too, how is it possible that I spend so much time on this problem before sending the question to stackoverflow and getting the answer in 5 minutes ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
import itertools
s = "AAABBBCDEEEEBBBAA"
["".join(chars) for _, chars in itertools.groupby(s)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another way of soloving your problem :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

string = 'AAABBBCDEEEEBBBAA'
memory = str()
List = list()
for index, element in enumerate(string):
    if index > 0:
        if string[index] == string[index - 1]:
            memory += string[index]
        else:
            List.append(memory)
            memory = element
    else:
        memory += element

print List
```