# Split string into strings of repeating elements

Tags: python

I want to split a string like:

```
'aaabbccccabbb'
```

into

```
['aaa', 'bb', 'cccc', 'a', 'bbb']
```

What's an elegant way to do this in Python? If it makes it easier, it can be assumed that the string will only contain a's, b's and c's.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split this string with python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940721/how-to-split-this-string-with-python)

Comment: No one suggested regular expressions? I am both impressed and saddened.

Comment: Yeah, it's a duplicate of the question Ethan linked to. But that question doesn't have a helpful title, IMO.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That is *the* use case for [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) :)

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> s = 'aaabbccccabbb'
>>> [''.join(y) for _,y in groupby(s)]
['aaa', 'bb', 'cccc', 'a', 'bbb']
```

Comment: I knew there'd be an easy way to do this!

Answer (score 3):

You can create an iterator - without trying to be smart just to keep it short and unreadable:

```
def yield_same(string):
    it_str = iter(string)
    result = it_str.next()
    for next_chr in it_str:
        if next_chr != result[0]:
            yield result
            result = ""
        result += next_chr
    yield result


.. 
>>> list(yield_same("aaaaaabcbcdcdccccccdddddd"))
['aaaaaa', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'd', 'cccccc', 'dddddd']
>>>
```

**edit**
ok, so there is itertools.groupby, which probably does something like this.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the best way I could find using regex:

```
print [a for a,b in re.findall(r"((\w)\2*)", s)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'aaabbccccabbb'
>>> [m.group() for m in re.finditer(r'(\w)(\1*)',s)]
['aaa', 'bb', 'cccc', 'a', 'bbb']
```